# Eliminar salto de linea al usar fgets en c

Tags: c, fgets

al leer un cadena de caracteres con fgets, este tambien guarda el salto de linea(\n), ¿como puedo eliminar ese salto de linea utilizando de todas maneras fgets para leer?
*No me sirve utilizar fscanf u otro formato para leer* Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

cuando leas la cadena de caracteres con `fgets`, utiliza `strtok(cadena, "\n")`
 para eliminar el salto de línea. también puedes eliminar el caracter directamente accediendo a la cadena como un array de caracteres.